# How to use JSON path wildcards in JSON_QUERY?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, json

For a minimal working example say I have a column storing JSON with a structure similar to the following.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(4000) = 
    '{"Dims": 
     [
      {"Name":"Apple", "Baking": ["Pie","Tart"], "Plant":"Tree"},
      {"Name":"Tomato", "Cooking":["Stew","Sauce"], "Plant":"Vine"},
      {"Name":"Banana","Baking":["Bread"], "Cooking":["Fried"], "Plant":"Arborescent"}
     ]}
'
```

This is valid JSON and scalars can be returned.

```
SELECT ISJSON(@json);
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.Dims[0].Name');
```

> ```
> Apple
> ```

However, when I use `JSON_QUERY` to return the names of all of the `"Dims"` SQL Server 2017 errors.

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(@json,'$.Dims[*].Name');
```

> ```
> Msg 13607, Level 16, State 4, Line 16
> JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '*' is found at position 7.
> ```

This should return

> ```
> ["Apple", "Tomato", "Banana"]
> ```

This is a valid standard JSON path. Any ideas why this is not working and how to get this to work on SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that is not currently supported, and would make a good [feedback item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server).

You can get the names into a resultset with a query like:

```
select json_value(v.value,'$.Name') Name
from openjson(@json,'$.Dims') v
```

And from there you can construct a new JSON doc, but if you want an array of primitives, you need to do something like this.

```
select concat('[',string_agg( quotename(json_value(v.value,'$.Name'), '"'), ', ')  WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY [key] )   ,']')
from openjson(@json,'$.Dims') v
```

I don't think there is a way to get an array of primitive values (ie not objects) with FOR JSON queries.

Comment: An suggestion has been posted on Microsoft's site ([908035](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/36595762-enable-json-path-wildcards-in-json-query)).

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. The pattern is to select the path down to the items with `OPENJSON` and then `JSON_VALUE` on the each item to extract the value.